# Why does Groot want money?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, groot

In *The Guardians of the Galaxy* we see Groot repeatedly express a desire for a share of any financial pay off. Rocket even comments on it:

> Asleep for the danger, awake for the money, as per frickin' usual.

However, what need does Groot have for money? He doesn't use weapons, wear clothes or appear to have any possessions. He drinks some alcohol in the bar scene but otherwise seems quite happy with public fountain water.

Furthermore it seems like those activities that they might have to pay for as part of their bounty hunting activities (e.g. interplanetary travel) would be naturally handled by Rocket as the boss and brains of the outfit.

So what would Groot have done with his share if they had ended up with some form of financial compensation?

Comment: He would use it to buy things. Things you can't get for free.

Comment: because he wants miracle-gro and a new gro-bulb.

Comment: He's a tree. Of course he's all about the green. Photosynthesis!

Comment: He just likes to be included.

Comment: Who doesn't want money?

Comment: Money doesn’t just grow on trees you know! A ha ha ha ha ha! Ha ha. Hm.

Comment: ah, damnit, @PaulD.Waite I was going to say the same thing! :D

Comment: @Paul great Pauls think alike.

Comment: Because money doesn't grow on trees?

Answer (score 16):

#### Groot uses money for the same reason anyone does. To buy things he needs or wants. Granted, when the comics or series interacts with the characters, we don't see him using very much money but that doesn't mean he doesn't need anything.

As we have reported in other posts, Groot comes from an advanced star-faring civilization and despite his apparently limited vocabulary, we know he is in fact, highly intelligent and may choose to use his funds gathered from bounty hunting to purchase resources, equipment, or other things we may simply not get to see.

We know less about the MCU Groot, but we can assume the pertinent parts of the character's bio are the same. He is intelligent, kind, friendly, and curious.

> If Groot could speak intelligently he would tell you Groot is no mere wood! The citizens of Planet X, where Groot came from were an advanced starfaring species complete with scientists and a curiosity about life in the Universe. In Guardians of the Galaxy we are never told what happened to the citizens of Planet X, only that Groot is the last survivor of that species.
>
> Groot's physical capacity for transformation, instantaneous growth and incredible durability ensure his survival under adverse conditions. He demonstrates an ability to spontaneously grow flowers, transform into vine-like barriers, and extend his limbs at will.

**From: [How does Groot's regeneration work](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64865/2765)**

In an interaction with Jean Grey, we see Groot's internal dialog for the first time, showing intense mental activity and significant cognitive ability behind every "I am Groot."

[image]

For all we know, Groot uses his share to establish parks, forests, nature preserves or other recreational facilities on planets. Groot's internal life is simply one we never get to know much about and have only Rocket's interpretation of events.

Comment: He spend his money on important things like equipment, necessities, and viiideo gaaaames.

Comment: "Except for Latverians. I really don't like them." HAHA - that's great!

Answer (score 1):

It was more to do with the fact of not being left out. It was not that he wanted the money, he wanted the companionship of everyone around him.

He is supposed to be very smart according to [Groot (Earth-616)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Groot_(Earth-616))

> Genius Intellect: Groot has received the finest education from
> Photonic Knowledge of the Arbor Masters. He was highly intelligent and
> has a tremendous grasp of quasi-dimensional super-positional
> engineering.

So it seems it was more a matter of principal than want or needs.

Comment: The comic and movie Groots are not the same character.

Answer (score -1):

Well there are 2 possible explanations-

Groot could use the money to help others. In the movie he is portrayed as wise and kind-hearted, despite his "speech problems". Especially when he gives the flower to the girl during the Knowhere scene. If he had money, donation would be my bet.

Alternatively, Rocket was simply exaggerating. After all, it is perfectly in-character for him to do so.

Comment: Or eat some plant food.